# Spaces homotopy equivalent over the topologist's sine curve

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider $$T=\left\{  \left( x, \sin \tfrac{1}{x}  \right ) :  x \in [-1, 0)\cup(0,1] \right\} \cup \{(0,0)\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$$
with the subspace topology.

Denote $p=(-1, \sin -1), q=(1, \sin 1)\in T$.

A TSC-homotopy between continuous maps $f, g:X\to Y$ is a continuous map $H:X\times T\to Y$ such that $H(x, p)=f, H(x, q)=g$.

Consider the following equivalence relation on topological spaces. $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent if there are continuous maps $f:X\to Y, g:Y\to X$ and homotopies $f\circ g\sim \mathrm{id}_Y, g\circ f\sim \mathrm{id}_X$.

What can be said about this equivalence relation?

Comment: This kind of homotopy is probably neither symmetric nor transitive, so it is not an equivalence relation.  This makes it unlikely that there is any useful answer to your question.

Comment: After your latest edit your relation on maps is now reflexive and symmetric, but still not transitive.  Because of that, the resulting relation on spaces is probably not transitive either.